# Is a Component optional to use in Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

There is one approach mentioned in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html#connecting-consumers-and-providers and other approch without using Component here http://antonioleiva.com/dagger-android-part-2/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please note that Dagger 2 and Dagger are *not* the same thing. If you read `ObjectGraph` you are probably reading about Dagger (1).

You *can not* use Dagger 2 without components. Components are the objects that hold your dependencies and know how to provide and inject them. I think the same holds true for Dagger 1 about their ObjectGraph. If you don't have the means to provide your dependencies, you can't use DI.

Comment: Thanks David. I got comple info https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2 and http://frogermcs.github.io/dagger-1-to-2-migration/